# How to identify abnormal data from large amount of data?

Tags: data-mining

I would like to ask theory or something to identify abnormal data from large amount of data.

```
For example:
Sequence data :2,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,2,2,2,3,3,7,7,3,2,...
Abnormal data :5,7
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a **robust** estimate of mean and standard deviation.

For example, median and MAD.

Then define a threshold such as median + 2 * MAD.